# copy each part of text to the specific place in file ( same file, global)

Tags: sed, awk

i have a problem with this.. the file looks like this

```
<p><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/ask/company/somefile.pdf" >somecrap</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/ask_me/company/somefile22122.pdf" >somecrap</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/ask_new/company/somefile22122.pdf" >somecrap</a></p>
```

part of text must be copied and inserted in right place (somecrap) in same file, each line must be
contain same url example

```
<p><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/ask/company/somefile.pdf" >http://www.mydomain.com/ask/company/somefile.pdf</a></p>`
<p><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/ask_me/company/somefile22122.pdf" >http://www.mydomain.com/ask_me/company/somefile22122.pdf</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/ask_new/company/somefile22122.pdf" >http://www.mydomain.com/ask_new/company/somefile22122.pdf</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off using a xml parser. For one off hack the following should work:

```
sed -r 's/href="([^"]+)" >[^<]+/href="\1" >\1/' file
```

It the output looks ok to you then you can use `-i` option to make in-file changes.

```
$ cat file
<p><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/ask/company/somefile.pdf" >somecrap</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/ask_me/company/somefile22122.pdf" >somecrap</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/ask_new/company/somefile22122.pdf" >somecrap</a></p>
```

```
$ sed -r 's/href="([^"]+)" >[^<]+/href="\1" >\1/' file
<p><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/ask/company/somefile.pdf" >http://www.mydomain.com/ask/company/somefile.pdf</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/ask_me/company/somefile22122.pdf" >http://www.mydomain.com/ask_me/company/somefile22122.pdf</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/ask_new/company/somefile22122.pdf" >http://www.mydomain.com/ask_new/company/somefile22122.pdf</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a clumsy awk way, works for your example:

```
awk -F'>[^<]+<' '{split($0,a,"\"");OFS=">"a[2]"<"}$1=$1' file
```